# What is the value of $\angle x + \angle y$ in the following diagram?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, angle

[image]

> $\angle p=30^\circ$, $\angle q=45^\circ$, $\angle r=50^\circ$, $\angle$
>   $s=25^\circ$. $\angle x + \angle y = ?$

Source: [Bangladesh Math Olympiad 2016 junior Category](https://www.matholympiad.org.bd/)

I could not find any ways to get  $\angle x + \angle y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an irregular hexagon so the sum of the interior angles is $720^\circ.$

$\angle p+\angle q +\angle r + \angle s + (360^\circ-\angle x) + (360^\circ - \angle y)= 720^\circ$
$30^\circ+45^\circ+50^\circ+25^\circ+360^\circ-\angle x+360^\circ-\angle y=720^\circ$
$150^\circ=\angle x+\angle y$

All the best for the olympiad.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and early blessings!

Comment: Me too. Brother in which class do you study?

Comment: Don't worry it will be published in Prothom Alo or in the Facebook groups

Answer (score 3):

Hint: The sum of the angles in an $n$-gon is $(n-2)\cdot 180^\circ$

Comment: did you mean that this diagram is a hexagon?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thanks I got the answer. But is all these type of diagrams are a polygon?

Comment: If it's made up of straight line segments like that, yes.